# Accessing calculated property in javascript object

Tags: javascript, function, object, javascript-objects

Why does the console print undefined when I access age property directly. I have to print calcAge  function first in order to get the value.

```
const Osama = {
    firstName: 'osama',
    lastName: 'Shaikh',
    birthyear: 1999,
    job: 'developer',
    friends: ['michael', 'peter', 'steven'],
    haslicense: true,
    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2021 - this.birthyear;
        return this.age;
    },

};
console.log(Osama.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

That object doesn’t have an `age` property to begin with.

You only assign it when you run the `calcAge` method.

Comment: Thank you just one more question if I give the object the age property before calcAge like this age: 2037 - this.birthyear, in same object it gives Nan when I try to access the value of birthyear

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking to assign a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for the `age` property.

```js
const Osama = {
  birthyear: 1999,

  get age() {
    console.log('in getter');
    return 2021 - this.birthyear;
  },
};

console.log(Osama.age); // in getter, 22
console.log(Osama.age); // in getter, 22
```

Or, to calculate the age only on first access and replace it with a static property you can use a [self-overwriting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters) getter.

```js
const Osama = {
  birthyear: 1999,
  
  get age() {
    console.log('in getter');
    delete this.age;

    return (this.age = 2021 - this.birthyear);
  },
};

console.log(Osama.age); // in getter, 22
console.log(Osama.age); // 22
```